# Prove this conclusion

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=A<\infty$，prove
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\dfrac{x^n}{n!}=A\text{e}^x(1+o(1)), x\to+\infty。 
$$

Here is my thought , let $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{x^k}{k!}}$,then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}}=S_na_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{S_k\left( a_k-a_{k+1} \right)}=A\text{e}^x+\cdots
$$
I don't know how I can get $(1+o(1))$.

Comment: This doesn't hold for $A = 0$. Generally, you want to prove that $a_n \to 0$ implies $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

The assertion to be proved is false. Take $a_n=2^{-n}$. Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x/2}$$

Comment: if $A\ne 0$，can it be proved？